# Getting a value from Dexie promise

Tags: javascript, promise, dexie

Trying to get data returned by the below function using `Dexie.JS`:

```
function findEvent(key) {
  let snippet = '';
  if (!db.isOpen()) {
    lastEvent = lastEvent.then(() => db.open());
  }
  lastEvent = lastEvent.then(() => db.transaction('r', db.events, () => {
    db.events.each((element) => {
      let d = element.cause.data;
      if (d.hasOwnProperty('deleted') && (false == d.deleted) && d.hasOwnProperty('abbreviation') && 
        d.hasOwnProperty('contents') && (d.abbreviation == key)) {
          console.log(`found matching snippet for key: ${key}, contents: ${d.contents}`);
          snippet = d.contents;
      }
    }).then(() => {
      console.log('search callback returning:', snippet);
      return snippet;
    });
  }));

  return lastEvent;
}
```

I call it as:

```
  return findEvent(request.key).then((result) => {
    console.log(`findEvent return: ${result}`);
  });
```

Apparently, I am doing something wrong. My promises are executed in the correct order. I get `snippet` printed correctly in the log from inside `findEvent`. When `result` is logged in the calling code, it is `undefined`.

What should be done differently?

Comment: if `db.events.each` returns a promise (doesn't look like it would, but I don't know), then you need to `return db.events.each`

Comment: so `console.log('search callback returning:', snippet);` logs correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not `return`ing the promise from `db.events.each`, so undefined gets piped into your top level promise.

Comment: What should I do?

Comment: `return db.events.each(...`

Comment: yes, missed that one. thank you. says that i can accept in 3 minutes. you are awesome, and i will accept.